# Meaning of time and distance in general relativity?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, spacetime

I have just started studying cosmology and I have realised that certain statements (that made perfect sense before I studied GR) no longer make sense:

-The universe is 13.2 billion years old.  What does this mean, time depends on the gravitational field and so is the universe younger on Mars?

-Galaxies are billions of light years away.  Again, distance doesn't hold well?

What do these sort of statements mean now space-time is warped?

Comment: That's why cosmologists use the redshift $z$ instead of distances, but there are several options when you do want actual distances or times. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_measures_(cosmology) has a good intro. Times are often given in the reference frame where the CMB is isotropic.